# Python return variable defined with raw_input

Tags: python, return

i wonder how to pass some variable through functions with return in python, if one function starts with raw_input
like this:

```
def function1():
    a = raw_input("Type something: ")
    return a

def function2():
    b = function1()       #i want b to get value of a
```

When i try this and try to print "b" it just shows me again "Type something: " and again and again

Comment: where are you printing b?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call function2

```
def function1():
    a = raw_input("Type something: ")
    return a

def function2():
    b = function1()
    print b
function2()
```

Comment: And is it possible to save value of 'a' and then later use it in some another function?
for example:
if I define function like first one and then later in another module I want to use that specific value of 'a' 
Because I have code in which I need value of 'a' several times so I don't want it to ask me to "Type something: " again.

Comment: define `'a'` `globally` before you call `function2()`